# JSF2 ui:repeat inputText wont re-render on first try

Tags: jsf-2, uirepeat

I have a ui repeat that contains a inputtext and command button pairs.  The button simply changes the value that the inputtext displays and re-renders it.  On the first button click it changes the value but does not re-render on the screen.  The second click does the same but successfully re-renders the control.  Onevent triggers all 3 status events just fine.  Nothing shows in the logs either.  The problem seems server side but i'm using the default faces setup from netbeans 7.3.1.

The below code will display 4 lines of inputValue and buttons.  The first works fine (its outside of the ui:repeat. The 3 below all require 2 clicks.

TestBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {
    private MyObject nc;
    private List<MyObject> list;

    public TestBean() {
        nc = null;
        list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    }

    public MyObject getNc() {
        return nc;
    }

    public void setNc(MyObject nc) {
        this.nc = nc;
    }

    public List<MyObject> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<MyObject> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void onInit() {
        MyObject nc1 = new MyObject();
        nc1.setText("1");
        list.add(nc1);
        MyObject nc2 = new MyObject();
        nc2.setText("2");
        list.add(nc2);
        MyObject nc3 = new MyObject();
        nc3.setText("3");
        list.add(nc3);

        MyObject nc0 = new MyObject();
        nc0.setText("0");
        nc = nc0;
    }
}
```

MyObject.java

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable {
    public String text;

    public MyObject() {
        this.text = "";
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void testMethod() {
        text = "HEY";
    }
}
```

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Hello from Facelets<br />
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText id="text" readonly="true" value="#{testBean.nc.text}" />
                    <h:commandButton value="test">
                        <f:ajax listener="#{testBean.nc.testMethod()}" execute="text" render="text" />
                    </h:commandButton><br /><hr />

            <ui:repeat value="#{testBean.list}" var="cur">
                <h:panelGroup id="viewTest">
                    <h:inputText id="text" readonly="true" value="#{cur.text}" />
                </h:panelGroup>

                    <h:commandButton value="test">
                        <f:ajax listener="#{cur.testMethod()}" render="viewTest" immediate="true" />
                    </h:commandButton><br />

            </ui:repeat>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ive replaced the ui:repeat with a h:datatable that seems to work.  Id like to figure out what ive done wrong otherwise.  Any insight would help :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Once I changed .testMethod() to .testMethod(AjaxBehaviorEvent ae) it works on the first click.  Apparently they get treated differently by JSF.  Hope someone else can learn from my mistake.